# set textbox width based on value retrieved from the database in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I wanted to set the width of a textbox based on the value assigned to the controls(binded to textbox) during the data is fetched from the db(mostly at init).

Once the page load and all the values assigned to the binded form control, the textbox should have width based on the values. I am not able to achieve this honestly. Below is the code I am using:

**HTML**

```
                    <td formArrayName="entityAttributeInfo" *ngFor="let item of paramTypes.get('entityAttributeInfo')['controls']; let ii = index;">
                        <div [formGroupName]="ii" class="tabledataEquipmentNameInfo">
                            <table *ngIf="item.get('uom').value!=''" style="width:100%">
                                <tr *ngIf="item.get('uom').value!=''">
                                    <td style="width:60%;">
                                        <input formControlName="value" class="form-control" style="border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;">
                                    </td>
                                    //this td element I want to assign width based on value retrieved from item.get('uom').value
                                    <td style="width:40%;">
                                        <input style="border-left: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;" formControlName="uom" class="form-control" [attr.disabled]="true" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

I wanted to handle it on HTML part. I have tried using min-width but, it doesn't work. I am attaching the screenshot of how the current html looks like based on this html.

Extra gap in the disabled textbox

[image]

Please note that the value can either be small or very large. Based on the value, I need to set the width. I have checked almost of the article online, but didnt got sufficient response.

Comment: Since this shall remain disabled, why not just use a `span` with a `background-color` why are you using an `input` element? `span` elements are inline containers that would perfectly fit the content.

Comment: I can use span, but the question remains the same. How to adjust the width?

Comment: Doesn't `span` auto adjust? i.e., they take as less or as more space the content is, this was the idea in the first place.

Comment: Span do auto adjust, but it will not adjust the textbox value. if the span value length is big, then it will display in two lines, thereby distorting the UI. Else I would have used it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an ngStyle attribute? `[ngStyle]="{width:VariableHere+'%'}"`

```
<input style="border-left: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;" 
formControlName="uom" 
class="form-control" 
[attr.disabled]="true" 
[ngStyle]="{width:VariableHere+'%'}"/>
```

If you want to use CSS rule with a hyphen in the name, then you will need quotes `[ngStyle]="{'min-width':VariableHere+'px'}"`